# How Can I write query in Subsonic for Subqueires

Tags: subsonic, subquery

How can I do the following query in subsonic 2.2

```
select Table1.Id, Table1.Name, Table1.Age from Table1
where Table1.Id =
(
select Max(T.Id) from Table1 T
Where T.Age = 20
)
```

Can one can provide me with example.

Thanks.
nRk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subsonic 2.2 can do sub-queries:

As Adam suggested, editted and improved example using In, this works for me:

```
SubSonic.Select s = new SubSonic.Select(SSDAL.Customer.CustomerIDColumn, SSDAL.Customer.NameColumn);
SubSonic.Aggregate a = new SubSonic.Aggregate(SSDAL.Customer.CustomerIDColumn, SubSonic.AggregateFunction.Max);
SSDAL.CustomerCollection COL = new SSDAL.CustomerCollection();
SubSonic.Select sq = new SubSonic.Select("LastCustomerId");
sq.Aggregates.Add(a);
sq.From(Tables.Customer);
a.Alias = "LastCustomerId";
s.From(Tables.Customer);
s.Where(SSDAL.Customer.CustomerIDColumn).In(sq);
COL = s.ExecuteAsCollection<SSDAL.CustomerCollection>();
;
```

This code produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT [dbo].[Customer].[CustomerID], [dbo].[Customer].[Name]
 FROM [dbo].[Customer]
 WHERE [dbo].[Customer].[CustomerID] IN (SELECT MAX([dbo].[Customer].[CustomerID]) AS 'LastCustomerId'
 FROM [dbo].[Customer])
```

Comment: You want to use In rather than IsEqualTo though

Comment: Hi, Zapatta
 Thanks,
I tried the same.. but it is giving error.. IsEqual is expecting a single value.. but query returning a collection.
And one more thing is, the Select statment converted to two different quries..not as a subquery which is not expecting.

Thank you

nrk

Comment: I have edited my original answer to include a sub-query sample that works for me and should work for you with some changes to suit. It uses In rather than IsEqualTo as suggested by Adam.

Answer (score 2):

Adam may be onto something but it looks a little ugly.  Here is an example that is a bit more readable that returns an IDataReader

```
new SubSonic.Select(Table1.IdColumn,Table1.NameColumn,Table1.AgeColumn)
.From(Table1.Schema)
.Where(Table1.IdColumn).In(new SubSonic.Select(Aggregate.Max(Table1.IdColumn)).From(Table1.Schema))
.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know there is no support for subqueries in SubSonic. You'll need to put the query in a sproc and use the generated SPs.SprocName() method.

EDIT: I was wrong, see other answer below.

Comment: SubSonic 2.1+ can handle SubQueries

Comment: Since I have been proven wrong below, I will delete this answer, but it needs to be unaccepted first since you can't delete an accepted answer.